# Copy rows with variable columns and paste transposed; offset to next available row and repeat

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro to copy 2 rows at a time from one sheet, transpose and paste in another worksheet.

As the next row contains calculated values, I want to skip it and go to the next row with values.The number of columns in each set is variable. 
The spreadsheet has 3 columns and 3rd column contains series which need to be copied.

I tried to offset the row by 4 (`fr = fr+4`) to find the next row with value (as there is a blank row after every set). 
This worked fine till it encountered a set with 4 values in previous column (which usually has 1 or 2 values).

Next resulted values were all incorrect as the offset value had to be changed accordingly. There are 1000s of rows, hence difficult to specify.

```
Sub form_detail()
    Dim t As Range, u As Range, rng As Range
    Dim lstrow As Long, lcol As Long, fr As Long, lr As Long

    fr = ActiveCell.Row
    lr = Sheets("Formulation details").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Do
        lcol = Sheets("Formulation details").Cells(fr,Columns.Count). End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set t = Sheets("Formulation details").Cells(fr, 3)
        Set u = t.Offset(1, lcol)
        Range(t, u).Copy

        lstrow = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Sheets("sheet2").Range("B" & lstrow + 1)
        rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
       fr = fr + 4
    Loop While fr < lr
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The problem and the expected is attached.
[image: Formulation detail, copy and paste transpose]

Also, I would like to copy the corresponding 1st column values (from source) for every row in the sheet2.  Kindly guide me with this. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Side note (not the solution): `Dim lstrow, lcol, fr, lr As Long` only declares the last one as `Long` all the others are of type `Variant`. You need to specify the type for **every** variable: `Dim lstrow As Long, lcol As Long, fr As Long, lr As Long`

Comment: Many thanks for the input. I will correct it in my code.